# Clear Navigator Routes history in function Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, navigator

In my app I have main_page screen and login screen, user can push to the login screen and pop, but when logging in I want to clear all routes in Navigator history before store the uid and pushRemoveUntil to main_page screen.

If i don't clear Navigator routes history, the main_page, that works with streams depending if the user is logged or not, reminds in second plane and gives an exception.

¿How can I clear all Navigator routes history pressing a button?

Comment: Please try this plugin. Its may help you..
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phoenix

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To do a cleaning of your navigation stack and also navigate to a specific page, try something like this:

```
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, "/newPage", (r) => false);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to clean my navigation stack without navigate to any page.

Comment: Same thing but with popUntil. ```Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/rootPage'));```